# How to decide between new Profile or use Permission set

Tags: permission-sets

Is there a tool(document) which decides if you have to create a new profile for the user or create a permission set and use existing profile. I would like to know for new user provisioning, once you get determine the access needed, is there a tool, which states "Create Permission set" and not a new Profile?
I know this appears to be a stupid question. But how can we avoid Profile Proliferation, by guiding the admin, to reuse the existing Profile or create a new profile, if the permission set cannot solve the issue.
Is there a decision tree document, which can assist the admin? Like-- Number of Users, access to what objects?, Reusing the existing profile etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that exists like this in standard Salesforce. It's one of those things that you have to document internally. I've used decision trees at my last company because there was a general concern about creating too many profiles to manage.

Another thing that you can do is create a permission menu. Create a menu that has groups of permissions for objects/permissions to cover 90% of your users and then when they want to create a new user the hiring manager chooses from the menu. By forcing users to choose from a menu of permissions you're shutting the door on one off types of access which avoids the need to create a bunch of psets.

Comment: Thanks @dan for your reply! You are right. It does not exist. Is there a way, I can get the document, that you had created? May be we can evolve it and then post it somewhere, that will help so many developers

Comment: I don't have it :( it's been lost to hard drive wipes.

Comment: I have created a document, which has the general AXIOMS(inviolable) which will be used to guide the admins

Comment: DO you remember what were those questions or factors, that determined the decision tree result?

Comment: Any questions that can help?

Comment: gotta ask yourself what are the large groups of users in your organization and then do they do the same things if yes then combine to a profile if they start to splinter access needs ask how many people are affected if it's more than say 10 maybe they need their own profile else make psets. Then divy up the access. When new requests come in ask does it affect more than 10 users then combine into the profile else make a pset.